# A noun describing an activity that one is really good at

Tags: word-request

What noun in English would be idiomatic to refer to an opportunity to participate in an activity that one is very good at and in which he normally can show his skills.

I am especially after a noun that would follow smoothly right after the word "real". Like here:

> His conversational skills are not great and his passive vocabulary is
> rather limited. This, however, somehow doesn't stop him from
> participating in our small in-class discussions. And his real _______
> is skits. That's when he does his best and shows off all his talent to
> the whole class.

Comment: Does [forte](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forte) suit your needs?

Comment: @Wehage - Yes, as long as it is idiomatic.

Comment: It is. See these [corpus search results](https://i.imgur.com/skqVtIr.png).

Comment: @Wehage - I see. Thank you!!!

Comment: In British English - ***strong suit***
n.
1. A quality, activity, or skill in which a person excels: Foreign policy was the president's strong suit.
2. In any of various card games, a long suit that contains high cards.  -  https://www.thefreedictionary.com/strong+suit

Comment: @Wehage - Can you, please, check your first link (Cambridge dictionary). Is the American pronunciation of that word correct there in that case? The British seems to be correct, but I am a bit doubtful about the American one.

Comment: @brilliant The phonetic transcription is correct, but the audio is wrong. The AmE pronunciation is similar to BrE, but rhotic.

Comment: @Wehage - Got it. Thanks again!

Comment: Lots of words can go in the blank, as well as the ones suggested in the comments and by James, there's: *talent*, *strength(s)*,  *shine at something* (e.g. he really shines at roleplaying/ad libbing), and *flair*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "[forte](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forte)" should suit your needs. It is idiomatic. See these [corpus search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLxsj.png). – ([Wehage](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/100665/wehage))  Note the American audio is incorrect at that link. It is pronounced "fo(r)tei" in both British and American.

Alternatively, in British English - "strong suit"

> n. 1. A quality, activity, or skill in which a person excels: Foreign policy was the president's strong suit. ([AHD via TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/strong+suit))